# English dialect used in titles

Tags: single-word-requests, titles, headline-english

Is there a name for dialect/variant of English that is commonly used in titles? The one that intentionally omits auxiliary verbs, articles and other words for shortness:

- Normal English: *The new album is now available, and it contains exclusive booklet inside.*
- “Title” English: *New album available, exclusive booklet inside*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such compressed language may be called *[headline English](http://eoimanresa.xtec.cat/eoimanresa/moodle/ANGLES/5/Miriam/Unit8/Vocabulary/Headline%20English.pdf)*—for which we even have a tag, [headline-english](/questions/tagged/headline-english)— or more jokingly, *[headlinese](http://books.google.com/books?id=V7U9c5ohh0kC&lpg=PA185&ots=R3YdQ2eHmn&pg=PA185#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, also the name of a book on the subject by Ingrid Mårdh.

Ah, headline English: home of the [article drop](http://people.umass.edu/aweir/Weir-2009-headlinese.pdf), land of the [crash blossom](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/01/31/magazine/31FOB-onlanguage-t.html).