# Is the omission of the verb "To be" in informative sentence

Tags: grammaticality

I have the following sentence:

**File (is) larger than allowed.**

Is the verb "to be" required here?

Is it correct English to use "File larger than allowed."?

Comment: If you remove the verb, it is no longer a sentence. It may be something else, however, like a label or an answer or a headline.

Comment: It is an example of telegraphic speech more commonly known as [headlinese](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131967/english-dialect-used-in-titles)

Comment: It's not a grammatical sentence in the first place. There should be a determiner before _File_. There is no English grammar for computer popups. You're on your own.

Comment: @John: Well, maybe "File" is a proper noun.  Baby names have gotten rather strange lately ;).

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly a sentence, we often get this kind of telegraphic answer from computers. Look at these examples:

> - "suitcase heavier than allowed" - from automatic scale at the airport
> - "file larger than allowed" - from a data traveler
> - "daily limit exceeded" - from an automatic teller machine