# Multiple errors found VS multiple errors were found

Tags: verbs, passive-voice

I'm writing a website where people can enter data and I want to show an error message if the data is incorrect.

I am debating whether the error should be "multiple errors found" or "multiple errors were found". The first sounds better to me even though the second seems more proper.

What's the way to go here?

Comment: I would suggest that most people using websites don't expect full English sentences in warnings and error messages so using the first one is acceptable in that context.

Comment: That would be fine. Does it match your wording for one error, e.g. *One error found*?

Comment: It's an error message.  Telegraphic syntax is normal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Fidel Castro Dead" - Is this Slang or common English Usage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360380/fidel-castro-dead-is-this-slang-or-common-english-usage) Or [Is the omission of the verb 'be' in informative sentence correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211699/is-the-omission-of-the-verb-to-be-in-informative-sentence/211704#211704)? Also [Is there a name for the abbreviated syntax used in signs etc?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251264/is-there-a-name-for-the-abbreviated-syntax-used-in-signs-etc/251267#251267)