# Why use active voice in "Five killed as aircraft hits shopping centre"?

Tags: passive-voice, ellipses, active-voice, headline-english

[image]

I think the five people were killed in the aircraft from this [news](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-39023903). The headline is:

> Melbourne plane crash: Five killed as aircraft hits shopping centre

Why use active voice rather than passive voice in this news headline?

Is the auxiliary verb dropped in this sentence? Is the full sentence "Five have been killed as aircraft his shopping centre"?

Comment: If you're referring to "five killed" (yellow highlighting), it's already in the passive voice.

Comment: Active would be "crash kills five".

Comment: Is the auxiliary verb dropped in this sentence?
The full sentence: Five have been killed as aircraft his shopping centre.

Comment: I have no idea why passive voice is not in the form of "[be] + [past participle of verb] "

Comment: @Lawrence What's the tense of "Five killed"?  I think it's simple past tense. Am I right?

Comment: Because it is "headlinese". Editors have their own criteria that do not include grammar.

Comment: @Cascabel  Is it kind of reduction?

Comment: Yup. [Look here.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language/104970#104970) Editors commonly remove articles, conjunctions and the verb "be" in passive use.

Comment: @Cody Yes, it's a shortened form of *five were killed*. Reading "five killed" as active makes the five out to be the killers.

Comment: Thank you for sharing these to me. I also found an [article](http://esl.about.com/od/intermediatereading/a/newsheadlines.htm) about this.

Comment: Actually I think the implied full sentence is "Five [are] killed as aircraft hits shopping centre." Cascabel correctly to identifies the wording as an instance of"headlinese." The main text of the story is expressed in past tense—as is fitting for a description of events that are now in the past. But the headline adopts present tense, presumably to give the reader a sense of immediacy about the event. You might read a story with the headline "Mars Attacked Earth Yesterday Afternoon"; but newspapers share a belief that you are even likelier to read one with the headline "Mars Attacks!"

Comment: related: [Why do newspaper headlines use strange syntax rules?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/why-do-newspaper-headlines-use-strange-syntax-rules)

Comment: Related: [Why is the present perfect used in headlines?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69323/why-is-the-present-perfect-used-in-headlines)

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language/104970#104970 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131967/english-dialect-used-in-titles http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language

Comment: Our local newspaper, The Roanoke Times, one Christmas morning headlined an automobile accident that had  occurred in Wise County the previous day: THREE WISE MEN KILLED IN ACCIDENT. There are less controversial ways to grab readers' attention, and one of them is to use the historical present tense, in which you use the present tense to narrate past events. The effect is to bring immediacy to a past event; it is a common literary device, not restricted to newspapers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Newspaper headlines are often written in a special style, which is
>   very different from ordinary English. In this style there are special
>   rules of grammar and words are often used in unusual ways.

*"Five **killed** as aircraft **hits** shopping centre" means Five (people) (have been) killed as an aircraft has hit a shopping centre.*

From **Michael Swan's Practical English Usage**: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. They can't be copied and pasted, they aren't indexed by search engines, and they don't adhere to browser text resizing among other problems. Transcriptions are far preferable, especially because you need to include them for the image alt text in the first place.

Comment: After some deliberation, I've upvoted this answer because Swan does a pretty magnificent job of summarising and explaining how headlinese is used in newspapers.

Comment: *BUT* choster is absolutely correct when he says screenshots are not searchable, by posting an image instead of transcribing the most relevant sections,  this post will not be shown if visitors or users type in the search box: ***Newspaper***, ***title***, ***passive tense***, ***ellipsis***. **present perfect**

Comment: Just *were killed* or *are killed*.

Comment: @tchrist ***five have been killed*** is perfectly fine, it is grammatical, but I find which follows; `... as an aircraft has hit a shopping centre` more worrisome.